# Sending http requests with cookies using ESP8266

Tags: arduino, esp8266

I wrote this API : 
https://github.com/prp-e/iot-api-temp-humid 
and when I tested it, I used this command :

```
curl -b cookies.txt http://localhost:8000/login/username/password
```

and each time I wanted to check the data in the "Enviroment" table, I use

```
curl -c cookies.txt http://localhost:8000/env/username
```

I need the cookies to be stored somewhere, or regenerate each time ESP8266 sends data to the API. is there any way?

Answer (score 1):

If the cookie data is small (fewer than 4096 bytes), you might store it using the [EEPROM](https://arduino-esp8266.readthedocs.io/en/latest/libraries.html#eeprom) class. Note that the ESP8266 doesn't really have an EEPROM (Arduinos generally do), so this is just writing the data to a reserved area of its flash storage.  Be sure to call `EEPROM.commit()` after you write or your changes won't actually be saved. The EEPROM documentation includes links to some examples of how to use it.

If the cookie data is larger, you can store it in a file using [SPIFFS](https://arduino-esp8266.readthedocs.io/en/latest/filesystem.html#file-system-object-spiffs). SPIFFS lets you use part of the ESP8266's flash storage as a simple filesystem.

ESP8266 boards usually have low quality flash storage which can only handle at most a few hundred thousand writes, so you don't want to write to the flash very frequently. For instance, if you updated the cookies in flash once per second, in just one day you'd write to the flash 86,400 times. Within two days you'd quite possibly wear out the sector of flash that was being used to store cookie values. So be careful with how often you change the values of the cookies and how often you write to the flash memory.

The ESP8266 also has 512 bytes of RAM associated with its real time clock (RTC). Data stored here will persist across reboots but will be lost if power is removed from the chip. Because it's normal RAM and not flash, it doesn't suffer from wear problems and can be rewritten safely. [Here's an example](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/tree/master/libraries/esp8266/examples/RTCUserMemory) of how to use it.